# Is Antlr a DSL generator and an alternative to Intentional Programming?

Tags: domain-driven-design, antlr, dsl, intentional-programming

I am struck by the ambition and creativity of Charles Simonyi's efforts to establish the field of Intentional Programming, first at Microsoft and then with his own company.

[What exactly is Intentional Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201386/what-exactly-is-intentional-programming)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentional_programming

> In this approach to software, a
>   programmer first builds a toolbox
>   specific to a given problem domain
>   (such as life insurance). Domain
>   experts, aided by the programmer, then
>   describe the program's intended
>   behavior in a What You See Is What You
>   Get (WYSIWYG)-like manner. An
>   automated system uses the program
>   description and the toolbox to
>   generate the final program. Successive
>   changes are only done at the WYSIWYG
>   level.

It seems to be such a useful and practical approach to programming, potentially circumventing many of the problems with current approaches to software development.

Essentially it seems to facilitate the creation of domain-specific languages by non-programmers (business/systems analysts) but at a stage much closer to real-life implementation than UML could provide. He says it will be completed eventually but that it is not there yet (almost 15 years later).

DSLs run the gamut from simple 5-line rule engines to complex applications like Ruby on Rails. So I imagine the delay in releasing his product has to do with the fact that he is dealing with simplifying a much higher level of abstraction because he has to essentially allow for the encapsulation of all domain languages at once.

So, my question is

**(a) whether [Antlr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) could be an alternative to Intentional Programming - although perhaps a less user-friendly alternative which requires the intervention of programmers rather than permitting business analysts to generate the DSL?** **Could you use Antlr to generate a DSL like Ruby on Rails (assuming it supported Ruby as an output - which I think it does not)? What can it not do? Also, I don't understand why it's called a "language parser" rather than a "language generator" - since the latter describes what it is used for while the former describes how it achieves its end result.**

and

**(b) if Antlr is different from Intentional Programming, is there anything similar to Intentional Programming?**

Comment: Is this a question or advertising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on this, so treat with a large pinch of salt.  However...

ANTLR itself is not a DSL generator, though it can be used to create code that interprets DSLs.  It is a parser generator - but the DSL generator would have to create what ANTLR generates a parser from.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to part b), three systems that work in a similar space are:

- [**JetBrains MPS**](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/index.html)
- [**Eclipse xText**](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)
- [**MetaCase MetaEdit+**](http://www.metacase.com/)

Each of these products has different strengths and weaknesses, but all of them fall into the category of [Language Workbenches](http://martinfowler.com/articles/languageWorkbench.html). Intentional Software's Intentional Workbench is possibly the most ambitious product in this category to date, but is also not generally available.

MPS and xText are free, open-source products. MetaCase is the most mature, and is a commercial product. All of them have a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR is just a parser generator. In any non-trivial DSL, writing the parser is less than 50% of the effort expended in implementing the DSL. The evaluator/rule engine/code generator/schedule or whatever else your DSL does, probably requires more work and can't be generated like a parser.